# Auto Increment Column in SQL how to assign in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, t);
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = DestTableName;
sqlBulk.BatchSize = 1000;
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);                   
t.Commit();
```

Error occurs if I assign my identity column value and if I do not assign it says "Null not allowed in primary key" column - what to do?

Comment: you want to add value in identity column yourself?

Comment: i don't know if i am correct try `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON` on destination table

Comment: No, i set Auto increment true in sql thats why i am not sending it value but it say,"Null Value not Allow."

Comment: if you don't want to insert identity don't use `KeepIdentity` option

Comment: thanks @bansi you are right data inserted thanks alot.........:)

Answer (score 0):

Please read below:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927181836/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102109-1.aspx

OR

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = (int)DetailLines;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.myTable";
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumnName", "DestinationColumnName");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumnName", "DestinationColumnName");


                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(datatable);
                }
```